# Linear mixed model for repeated measure in R

Tags: mixed-model

I've been struggling to find right measures for my study.

I treated my patients with drug A and placebo, and measured FEV1 in 4 different time.

I regarded treatment and time as fixed effect, and ID (patients' ID) as random effect.

I tried coding as below

(fm<- lmer(FEV1~  time + treatment + time:treatment +(time|ID),data=CB2,control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")))

Is there something wrong with this design?
Some results came up and I couldn't understand it.
There was no p-value, only random/fixed effect was shown.